trace if file has been uploaded correctly on ftp via php
I need to trace, store a value (1 or 0) into mysql database, if a file has been successfully upload.
What I want is to be sure that the user uploaded the file and the transfer was ok, so with no errors/failed or similar.
Is there a way to do this?
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, TRUE);
$file = $filename2;
$rfile = $remote_dir.$file2;
if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $rfile, $file, FTP_ASCII))  { }
ftp_close($ftp_conn);


If you're asking for SQL to use in your if-statement, you maybe should provide a rough table definition. The answer would be to the effect of UPDATE <table-name> SET TRANSFERRED=1 WHERE FILE_NAME=?. The if-statement would need an else-case.

The FTP protocol uses TCP, which ensures reliable data transfer. And the server doesn't return a success response until it has received the complete file. ftp_put() uses this to determine whether to return true or false. So just check for this in your code:
$result = ftp_put($ftp_conn, $rfile, $file, FTP_ASCII);
// store $result in the database

